# Observium and SNMP parameters

Tags: windows, snmp

I have installed observium on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS server.
Now, I am trying to add a windows 7 instance device to observium.
But, when I try to add the device the following message appears:

```
root@observium:/opt/observium# ./add_device.php debian public 
Observium CE 0.14.11.6000
Add Device(s)

Try to add debian:
Trying v2c community public ...
No reply on community public using v2c.
Could not reach debian with given SNMP parameters using v2c.
Trying v1 community public ...
No reply on community public using v1.
Could not reach debian with given SNMP parameters using v1.
Devices skipped: 1.

USAGE:
add_device.php <hostname> [community] [v1|v2c] [port] [udp|udp6|tcp|tcp6]
add_device.php <hostname> [any|nanp|anp|ap] [v3] [user] [password] [enckey] [md5|sha] [aes|des] [port] [udp|udp6|tcp|tcp6]
add_device.php <filename>

EXAMPLE:
SNMPv1/2c:                    add_device.php <hostname> [community] [v1|v2c] [port] [udp|udp6|tcp|tcp6]
SNMPv3   :         Defaults : add_device.php <hostname> any v3 [user] [port] [udp|udp6|tcp|tcp6]
           No Auth, No Priv : add_device.php <hostname> nanp v3 [user] [port] [udp|udp6|tcp|tcp6]
              Auth, No Priv : add_device.php <hostname> anp v3 <user> <password> [md5|sha] [port] [udp|udp6|tcp|tcp6]
              Auth,    Priv : add_device.php <hostname> ap v3 <user> <password> <enckey> [md5|sha] [aes|des] [port] [udp|udp6|tcp|tcp6]
FILE     :                    add_device.php <filename>

ADD FROM FILE:
 To add multiple devices, create a file in which each line contains one device with or without options.
 Format for device options, the same as specified in USAGE.
```

I have enabled snmp service on Windows 7, the devices ping each other, computer name is added to /etc/hosts on observium but the device cannot be added to observium.
From the above message, I cannot understand what the problem is as I don't see any choice configuring snmp parameters on Windows 7 except community.

Answer (score 3):

You need configure SNMP agent to accept requests from remote hosts. To configure SNMP agent in windows, follow the steps given below:

1. Click **Start**, point to **Settings**, and then click **Control Panel**. Double-click **Administrative Tools** and then double-click **Computer Management**.
2. In the console tree, click **Services and Applications** and then click **Services**.
3. In the details pane, scroll down and click **SNMP Service**.
4. On the **Action** menu, click **Properties**.
5. On the **Security** tab, select **Send authentication** trap if you want a trap message to be sent whenever authentication fails.
6. Under **Accepted community names**, click Add.
7. Under **Community Rights**, select a permission level for this host to process SNMP requests from the selected community.
8. In **Community Name**, type a case-sensitive community name, and then click Add.
9. Specify whether or not to accept SNMP packets from a host:

   - To accept SNMP requests from any host on the network, regardless of identity, click **Accept SNMP packets from any host**.
   - To limit acceptance of SNMP packets, click **Accept SNMP packets from these hosts**, click Add, type the appropriate host name and IP or IPX address, and then click Add again.
10. Click **Apply** to apply the changes.

I hope this help.

Comment: I have done exactly what the above guide says but it doesn't work. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @user200913 check the step **Accept SNMP packets from any host** or **Accept SNMP packets from these hosts**, you can check in linux host with the following commnad `snmpwalk -v 2c -c <community_name> <ip_win_host>`

Comment: I ran the command you mentioned above and some results came up. But now, what I should do?

Comment: @user200913 try `add_device.php <ip_win_host> <community> v2c`

Comment: It worked!! Thanks a lot Federico Sierra! But could you explain me please what we did and now it worked? Because the only thing I made different this time was the command snmpwalk.

Comment: @user200913 I think the solution is use the correct version of snmp in observium command (`v2c`). Take a look in http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/FAQ:General_13 and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379100%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: When I ran the command before snmpwalk, I ran like add_device.php <hostname> <community> v2c and nothing happened. But after snmpwalk, it worked.

Comment: ok, I don't know if [snmpwalk](http://linux.die.net/man/1/snmpwalk) has to do with the solution, apparently in Windows you need to wait a while until the snmp information is available, I think this is the case. I dont have much experience with Windows, and is unpredictable for me ;-).

Comment: It doesn't matter as your help was really priceless. Thank you again very much. Now I added my second Windows device (Windows Server 2008 R2).